# Warning from Eclipse and android.view.InflateException at runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I've been getting occasional exception reports from my users when inflating a layout:

> android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class com.MyClass

It happens rarely and I've never seen it myself... until now. Suddenly I get that exception every time, using the exact same layout that I've been using all along:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.comet.android.keyboard.CandidateView
        android:id="@+id/candidate"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </com.comet.android.keyboard.CandidateView>

    <include layout="@layout/keyboard_view" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In addiation, Eclipse has always reported this warning on line #1:

> No grammar constraints (DTD or XML schema) detected for the document.

Any ideas on why I would get a warning on line #1 and an exception on line #2? Are the two related? This file worked until today and I didn't change it!

I've noticed that the namespace URL http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android doesn't resolve. Could that be it? It is the same URL used in all the Android examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is harmless. If you want to get rid of it look here http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=9831

The error is strange... could you post the code you use to inflate the layout? Also do you have a class called `com.MyClass`?

Comment: The error disappeared after I completely cleaned all my projects and re-installed the app from scratch. However I've been getting reports from the field of the same exception. Here is the line that inflates the layout above: mKeyboardLayout = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard_layout, null);
It's pretty straightforward. "com.MyClass" was supposed to be a placeholder for the actual class name but it's an error on my part. The exception just says "...error inflating class" and doesn't mention any class name.